# MySQL querying transition states

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and one of my project is to find transition states of issue from one status to another (see enclosed image) stored in MySQL JIRA database.

I sorted all data based on issue id followed by transition dates to order the data.

If you look at the first two rows you would see transition date of an issue from open to fixing. On the second row the same issue moves from fixing to on hold. I need to find out the days issue remained in Fixing state.

In excel or using 2D arrays it doesn't seem that difficult but with SQL ... it seems impossible. Any suggestion and pointers kindly appreciated :).

[image]

Comment: You need to join the table to itself.

Comment: when I do a join, how to I reference the column above it?

Comment: having a column named "From" in SQL is just asking for added headache.  If it's not too late change it so that a reserved word isn't being used.

Comment: @codeBarer Use a table variable for the row number.

Comment: @xQbert thanks :). I made From and To up, the original name used are added and removed (just as bad I guess).

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I've never used table variable, but after Googling it I found some resource that I'll try and use to make this magic happen :)

Comment: @codeBarer do you want 7 days or 16 days? issue 1 goes from hold to fixing again if you see the data. either way, I updated the fiddle to give you both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a table based on what you mentioned and here is the schema and the query.

```
CREATE TABLE tableName 
    (
     tID int , 
     startDate date,
      transitionDate date,
      fromStatus varchar(10),
      toStatus varchar(10)
    );
```

Pay extra attention to the `NOT EXISTS` subquery. tID 1 goes in and out of `fixing` so this takes care of incorrect calculations.

```
SELECT t1.tID,  sum(t2.transitionDate - t1.transitionDate)
FROM tableName t1, tableName t2
WHERE t1.tID = t2.tID AND t1.toStatus = "F" AND t2.fromStatus = "F" 
    AND t1.transitionDate <= t2.transitionDate AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableName t3 where t3.toStatus = "F" AND
              t3.transitionDate != t1.transitionDate AND
              t3.transitionDate != t2.transitionDate AND
              t3.transitionDate BETWEEN t1.transitionDate AND t2.transitionDate)
GROUP BY t1.tID
```

If you want the counts for every time the issue was being fixed -

```
SELECT t1.tID,  (t2.transitionDate - t1.transitionDate)
FROM tableName t1, tableName t2
WHERE t1.tID = t2.tID AND t1.toStatus = "F" AND t2.fromStatus = "F" 
    AND t1.transitionDate <= t2.transitionDate AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableName t3 where t3.toStatus = "F" AND
              t3.transitionDate != t1.transitionDate AND
              t3.transitionDate != t2.transitionDate AND
              t3.transitionDate BETWEEN t1.transitionDate AND t2.transitionDate)
GROUP BY t1.tID, t1.transitionDate
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81197/4)

If possible add a primary key (identity) so that the date comparisons can be replaced by the primary key.

Comment: Awesome! I'll add primary key and index my tables then all that is left is dumping it into a bar chart.  Thank you so much Lobo!

Comment: @codeBarer I hope you understood why the query works. Keep learning.

Comment: I think I do but as I play with it more, I am sure it will become clearer. DB stuff is so different from programming. My backup plan was to load the data into arrays using python and crunch it out. This so much simpler.